# ¿Cómo emular el AVD de android studio en virtualbox?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox

Instale Android Studio en una maquina virtual (Windows 8.1 x64) con el virtual box, pero a la hora de ejecutar mi app o correr el emulador AVD me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo y las soluciones son instalar el IntelHAXM, pero se que eso se instalo junto con el SDK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra solución que visto es activar esta casilla en la configuración de la maquina virtual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero por ahora ninguna de las dos opciones ha funcionado, también he leído que es imposible que funcione con el virtualbox y que si funciona con el VMware Workstation, pero primero quiero descartar el virtualbox para migrar todo a VMware. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: podrías aclarar si cuando dices virtual box te refieres a la maquina virtual propiedad de oracle? o a cualquier maquina virtual? otra cosa, tu pregunta se refiere a poder cambiar la maquina virtual no tu emulador android (AVD) cierto?

Comment: Si, me refiero al emulador virtual box de oracle, donde montas uno o más sistemas operativos... Mi pregunta es prácticamente era como solucionar el error que me sale al ejecutar el AVD de android en virtual box.

Comment: Ya probaste con Genymotion? @Hander , actualiza información de lo que hayas encontrado. Saludos.

Comment: Virtual box no puede emular otro emulador, es decir, no acepta "maquinas virtuales anidadas" y es por esto que no podrás ejecutar AVD en Virtual Box en cambio en VMware si puedes ejecutar AVD. Si para ti es obligatorio el uso de AVD entonces debes cambiar a VMware ahora si no es obligatorio el uso de AVD para ti pues lo mejor es tomar en cuenta la recomendación de @Jorgesys. El hecho es que dependiendo de tu necesidad o no de usar AVD ya Jorgesys y yo te dimos las dos soluciones posibles. Un Saludo

Comment: No puedes virtualizar dentro de una maquina virtual...

Answer (score 0):

> Otra solución que visto es activar esta casilla en la configuración de
>   la maquina virtual:
>
> Pero por ahora ninguna de las dos opciones ha funcionado, también he
>   leído que es imposible que funcione con el virtualbox y que si
>   funciona con el VMware Workstation, pero primero quiero descartar el
>   virtualbox para migrar todo a VMware.

Me es dificil explicarlo pero lo intentaré desglosando en varias partes:

1) Lo de la activación de la casilla en la maquina virtual, en virtual box es un mero adorno no funciona aún cuando lo activas... Todos los usuarios de virtual box lo critican desde hace mucho tiempo. En VMware si que funciona.

2) VT-x (HAXM) es un problema el sólo. Tengo una laptop que "soporta" VT-x e intente todo lo que encontré en internet para hacerlo funcionar pero parece que el VT-x de por sí es un bug viviente. De hecho en mi bios sale para activarla (pero aún cuando lo intenté nada sucedió) y eso que no era en maquina virtual sino en el propio host. Mi recomendación es que te asegures que verdaderamente tienes el VT-x activado en tu host como primer paso

3) Cuanto antes trabajes con VMware más lo agradecerás. Por qué? pues porque virtual box tiene muchos problemas de compatibilidad. Desde el detalle de la extensión que hay que instalar para no tener problemas con el puntero, pasando por los extraños errores que suceden a veces cuando tienes una carpeta compartida entre el host y la maquina virtual hasta llegar a su incompatibilidad absoluta con la mayoría de los antivirus (llegará un momento que quizás cambies el antivirus y luego intentes acceder a virtual box y te arroje uno de sus tantos errores sin sentido).

4) Sumado a todo lo anterior lamento decir que debes descartar virtual box debido a que no acepta aún (y he visto información por internet que data de antes del 2014 con personas que piden esa mejora) esta característica... sólo VMware es capaz de reproducir virtualización anidada como es tu caso (maquina virtual dentro de maquina virtual o lo que es lo mismo AVD dentro de virtual box). Así que cambia a VMware y en 1 o 2 días tendrás todo funcionando con la nueva carecteristica con mucho mejor rendimiento (y menos dolores de cabeza)

Aunque no es la respuesta que esperabas es la solución a tu problema. Espero haberte ayudado. Te dejo una referencia de un usuario que logró trabajar con el AVD en VMware por si queda alguna duda. Es de [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729150/is-it-possible-to-run-android-device-emulator-via-android-studio-2-on-vmware)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71005/discussion-on-answer-by-huskie-como-emular-el-avd-de-android-studio-en-virtualb).

Answer (score -2):

He visto algunas publicaciones donde aseguran que el emulador funciona teniendo instalado "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)", sinceramente no creo sea posible ya que el mismo mensaje que agregas en tu publicación indica que necesitas ejecutar el emulador en un OS no virtualizado.

Las opciones son:

> - Usar un dispositivo fisico.
> - Evitar un ambiente virtualizado.
> - O utilizar un dispositivo virtual Android basado en una imagen del sistema ARM.

Mi recomendación en este caso es usar [**Genymotion**](https://www.genymotion.com/) que funciona sin problemas con VMWare.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71007/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-como-emular-el-avd-de-android-studio-en-virtua).

Comment: De hecho si, quisiera ejecutar un dispositivo físico como mi android en la máquina virtual, pero no me funcionan los dispositivos instalados en la máquina virtual, me sale el siguiente error: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128662/error-al-conectar-usb-en-virtual-box